# NullPointerException when I try to read a Vector passed through Intent

Tags: java, android, android-intent, nullpointerexception, parcelable

I'm trying to use Parcelable classes to give a Stack from an activity to another. In order to do this I defined MyStack and MyVector3 in the following way. This is then included in a Model class.

Model class

```
public class Model implements Parcelable{
public List<MyStack> surfaces;
public Info info;

public Model (){}
public Model(List<MyStack> surf){
    surfaces = surf;
}

public void setInfo(Info i){
    info=i;
}

public Info getInfo(){
    return info;
}

public List<MyStack> getSurfaces(){
    return this.surfaces;
}

public int numSurfaces(){
    return surfaces.size();
}

public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

public void writeToParcel(Parcel out, int flags) {
    out.writeTypedList(surfaces);
    //Parcelable infoP = ((Parcelable) info);
    //out.writeParcelable(infoP, 0);
}

public static final Parcelable.Creator<Model> CREATOR
        = new Parcelable.Creator<Model>() {
    public Model createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new Model(in);
    }

    public Model[] newArray(int size) {
        return new Model[size];
    }
};

private Model(Parcel in) {
    surfaces = new ArrayList<MyStack>();
    in.readTypedList(surfaces, MyStack.CREATOR);
    //info = in.readParcelable(Info.class.getClassLoader());
}

public class Info{
    String title;
    String descr;

    public Info(String t, String d){
        title=t;
        descr=d;
    }

    public Info(String t){
        title=t;
    }

    public void setDescr(String d){
        descr=d;
    }
}
```

}

MyStack class

```
public class MyStack implements Parcelable {
public Stack<MyVector3> stack;

public MyStack(MyStack ms){
    this.stack=ms.stack;
}

public MyStack(Stack s){
    stack= s;
}

public Stack getStack(){
    return this.stack;
}

public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

public void writeToParcel(Parcel out, int flags) {
    out.writeTypedList(stack);
}

public static final Parcelable.Creator<MyStack> CREATOR
        = new Parcelable.Creator<MyStack>() {
    public MyStack createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new MyStack(in);
    }

    public MyStack[] newArray(int size) {
        return new MyStack[size];
    }
};

private MyStack(Parcel in) {
    stack= new Stack<MyVector3>();
    in.readTypedList(stack, MyVector3.CREATOR);
}
```

}

MyVector3 class

```
public class MyVector3 extends Vector3 implements Parcelable {
public Vector3 vector;

public MyVector3(Vector3 v){
    vector=v;
}

public MyVector3(double x, double y, double z){
    vector= new Vector3(x,y,z);
}

public Vector3 getVector(){
    return this.vector;
}

public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

public void writeToParcel(Parcel out, int flags) {
    out.writeDoubleArray(new double[]{
            this.x,
            this.y,
            this.z});
}

public static final Parcelable.Creator<MyVector3> CREATOR
        = new Parcelable.Creator<MyVector3>() {
    public MyVector3 createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new MyVector3(in);
    }

    public MyVector3[] newArray(int size) {
        return new MyVector3[size];
    }
};

private MyVector3(Parcel in) {
    double[] data = new double[3];
    in.readDoubleArray(data);

    this.x= data[0];
    this.y= data[1];
    this.z= data[2];
}
```

}

This is the intent creation, where the model is well populated and I get all values correctly from Logs

```
Model model= new Model(surfaces);

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, EditorPresenter.class);
    intent.putExtra("model", model);
    startActivity(intent);
```

And where I use it

```
 Intent intent = getIntent();
    model= intent.getParcelableExtra("model");
    MyStack[] sf = model.surfaces.toArray(new MyStack[model.numSurfaces()]);
    //surf = new Stack();
    surf = new Stack[model.numSurfaces()];
    Log.i(TAG, "ss="+Integer.toString(sf.length));  //expected value
    for(int s=0; s<sf.length; s++) {
        Log.i(TAG, "s="+Integer.toString(s));     //expected value
        Stack st= new Stack();
        Log.i(TAG, "vv="+Integer.toString(sf[s].getStack().size()));     //expected value
        for(int v=0; v<sf[s].getStack().size(); v++) {
            Log.i(TAG, "v="+Integer.toString(v) +sf[s].stack.elementAt(v).getVector().toString());  //NullPointerException
            MyVector3 mv = (MyVector3) sf[s].stack.elementAt(v);
            if(mv!=null) st.add(mv.getVector());
        }
        surf[s]=st;
    }
```

But I get a NullPointerException anytime I try to read/write a Vector3 value.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String org.rajawali3d.math.vector.Vector3.toString()' on a null object reference
```

The problem is probably in Parcelable classes, til I get a wrong model back from the intent (number of faces and vertices expected are right, vector values are probably null). Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are not instantiating your Vector object, after reading from parcelable. Change

```
private MyVector3(Parcel in) {
  double[] data = new double[3];
  in.readDoubleArray(data);

  this.x= data[0];
  this.y= data[1];
  this.z= data[2];
}
```

with

```
private MyVector3(Parcel in) {
    double[] data = new double[3];
    in.readDoubleArray(data);

    this.x= data[0];
    this.y= data[1];
    this.z= data[2];
    vector = new Vector3(x,y,z);
}
```

Comment: The second one is working, but all vectors I get are like this:

Vector3 <x, y, z>: <0.0, 0.0, 0.0>

Comment: If I were in you I would start logging the values of x, y and z when `writeToParcel` is invoked to check if you are storing the correct values

Comment: Yes, I just tried it, and all values are 0.0 for some reason.

If I do the same from the model before I pass it to the intent they are all correct.

Comment: ok then the problem lays somewhere else. try to debug it. You are not able to find the issue just ask a new question or edit this one adding more snippets of code

Comment: Solved.

    `public void writeToParcel(Parcel out, int flags) {

        out.writeDoubleArray(new double[]{
                this.vector.x,
                this.vector.y,
                this.vector.z});
    }`

Thank you a lot for the help.

Comment: Calling `this(x, y, z)` from the constructor after setting other values as in your first example cannot possibly compile. The Java compiler needs calls to other constructors to be on the first line.

Comment: @Amos, thanks for pointing that out. I must have been very our lf my mind to write that thing

Comment: @Blackbelt: No worries, happy to remove the downvote and turn it into an upvote. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can generate Parcelable classes from your code using this tool http://www.parcelabler.com/ and try again with new generated classes.